# How to make C functions agnostic to data type

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, type-conversion

I have been working on a simple library in C to handle arrays, dynamic arrays and linked lists.  As a starting point I have been working on a function to pop a user defined index from an array.  For starters I am working an an integer array and came upon this solution.

```
int pop_int_array(int *array, int index, int size) {
    int type = sizeof(int);
    if (index >= size) return 0;
    unsigned char *dst = (unsigned char*) array + index + type;
    memmove(dst, dst + type, type * (size - index - 1));
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    pop_int_array(a, 2, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

This yields the following output as expected

```
1
2
4
5
```

If I wanted to pop a `float` array, I would need to create a new function titled `pop_float_array` that copied all of the contents from `pop_int_array` but instead of using `int type = sizeof(int)` I would replace it with `int type = sizeof(float)`, and of course the array data type would be a `float` instead of an `int`.  However, this violates a core principle of software development by repeating the same code several times, where each time would be an implementation for a data type.  In order to get around this I re-wrote the function in the following way where the array is declared as a `void` data type.  In addition I cast the array to a `void *` in the main program before or during the process of passing it to the function.

```
int pop_array(void *array, int index, int size, int type) {
    if (index >= size) return 0;
    unsigned char *dst = (unsigned char*) array + index + type;
    memmove(dst, dst + type, type * (size - index - 1));
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    pop_array((void *)a, 2, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    float b[5] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
    pop_array((void *)a, 2, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

As expected this yields

```
1
2
4
5

1.1
2.2
4.4
5.5
```

This allows me to only create and maintain one function.  However, this seems so simple that I am surprised it is not a more widely used technique, or at least that I am aware of in my little experience.  Is there some consequence of writing the function this was or casting the array to a `void *` that I am not seeing, or is this a legitimate way to make a function type agnostic in C?

Comment: That kind of use of `void*` pointers is often avoided by using `#define` macros instead (which has its own world of gotchas). Another reason it is avoided is, it's not type safe, meaning the compiler can not warn you if you eg. got wrong size. And type safety is highly valued these days (I mean, consider Typescript and Python mypy). If there is a big need for generics, often a different language is chosen.

Comment: It is not so much a need for generics, it is a need to minimize code so that the library is more easily maintained, and not repeat the exact same code four different times, for four different data types.

Comment: That's precisely what generics do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing this is fine.  But you do have one mistake:

```
unsigned char *dst = (unsigned char*) array + index + type;
```

You're not moving up by the right amount.  This should be:

```
unsigned char *dst = (unsigned char*) array + (index * type);
```

Also, you don't need to cast to `void *` when you call the function:

```
pop_array(a, 2, 5, sizeof(int));
```

This technique is used in the `qsort` function which can sort an array of an arbitrary type.  It's signature is as follows:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

As with your function, it takes a `void *` to the start of the array as well as the number of elements and the size of each element.  It also takes a function pointer whose job is to perform the type specific comparison.